# Open href link in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I'm trying to open the link in popup, i've write this static html code :

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="popup" 
    onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','popup','width=600,height=600');   
    return false;"> Open Link in Popup
</a>
```

this code works, it open the link in popup.

But, if i want to add this code in javascript (with jquery) like this :

```
$('#services').append("<li><a href='http://www.google.com' target='popup' onclick='window.open('http://www.google.com','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;'>Open Link in Popup</a></li>");
```

The link is opened in new tab and not in popup.

Why ?

Comment: remove target='popup' from append clause and set href="#"

Comment: when i  remove target, the current href is replaced by the new href

Comment: set href="#" as i wrote before: `$('#services').append("<li><a href='#'  onclick='window.open('http://www.google.com','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;'>Open Link in Popup</a></li>");`

Comment: Nothing happen when i set href to #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KVC/2378/)  - Problem is in quotes

```
$('#services').append("<a href='http://www.google.com' target='popup' onclick=window.open('http://www.google.com','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;>Open Link in Popup</a>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed to escape the quotes in `onClick` of your jQuery. Update the script as below.

```
$('#services').append("<li><a href='http://www.google.com' onclick=\"window.open('http://www.google.com','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;\">Open Link in Popup</a></li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your algorithm, instead of putting the javascript inside onclick, add a class or ID, with data-, so you can attach your jQuery event handler on that class/ID, and use the data to create new window. Imagine the data as data-destination="http://www.destination".

That should fix your problem.

Comment: Have you a simple example for this ?